# Jquery dropdown menu - css hover overlap of image

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have the following jquery drop down menu:

http://kwedsd.byethost7.com/2.html

when you hover any top level link a green horizontal bar occurs (hover state), if you carefully look the green horizontal bar overlaps the border buy approx 2 px please can anyone advise how I can change the css to stop this overlap occurring.

Also for ease of viewing I have included an image. (red square showing the overlap)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the following solves it for me:

```
.ddsmoothmenu ul li a {
  margin-right:2px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it should have been easy for me to spot, but I guess that its just been a too long day! once again thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is not a border, but a background image of the `<li>` element looking like a border. As such, it is actually inside the `<li>` and can thus be covered by the `<a>` tag inside. Since the `<a>` has transparent background the issue doesn't show until the :hover border is added. Try setting a background-color on the `<a>` and you will see it covers the whole background-image of the `<li>`.

Add a `padding-right: 2px` to the `<li>` and you should be good, as this will protect the "border-like" bit of the background image from being covered by the `<a>`.

Comment: thanks, for the response yes I forgot to mention the border wasn't a proper border just an image. But thanks for your answer.